# i have a requirement to use REGEX for filenames, and the current REGEX is not working

Tags: regex

i am getting different filenames which contains some numbers first, then a word and then some more characters like date time stamp etc..

Ex: `9999_ORDERS_20190808.dat`

i use the REGEX as this :

```
([0-9])\w+.([A-Za-z])\w+_ORDERS_([0-9])\w+.([A-Za-z])\w+
```

But its not working,

i am getting the log as No suitable configuration found

Answer (score 0):

The amount of minimum characters does not match the example data. When you use a quantifier `+` requires at least 1 character to be there.

One of the reasons the pattern does not match is because after `ORDERS` you want to match a digit `([0-9])` which is not in the data.

You could use quantifiers for the character classes that should match 1+ 
digits and note to escape the dot to match it literally.

Using `\w` would also match a digit or an underscore, but it might be less confusing to match it literally for this example data and to make sure the underscore is actually there.

You could use anchors to assert the start `^` and end `$` of the string:

```
^[0-9]+_ORDERS_[0-9]+\.\w+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojuVKa/1)

Or use word bounaries `\b`

```
\b[0-9]+_ORDERS_[0-9]+\.\w+\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits
- `_ORDERS_` Match literally
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits (or `[0-9]{8}` to match exactly 8 digits if that is fixed for the timestamp)
- `\.\w+` Match a literal dot and 1+ word characters
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUBQkh/1)